# Router-link url changed but not redirect

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I clicked the button and the url changed but the page no redirect to monthlyIncomeStatementPrint

```
<td><ion-button expand="block">
<router-link :to="{name: 'getMonthlyIncome', params : {cMonthcsid: SelectedMonthandYear} }">Print</router-link>
</ion-button></td>
```

```
router
  {
    path: '/bonus/monthlyIncomeStatementPrint',
    name: 'getMonthlyIncome',
    component:monthlyIncomeStatementPrintPage,
    props:true,
  }
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciSAm.png)

Comment: Show your router config

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-haze-jx2xcq?file=/src/index.js here is the router config @tauzN

Comment: routes array is not closed. You are trying to use types in a js file. Your code is not even valid javascript. Fix it, or post the actual code.